# FB Graph API How can I get the list of all user ever logged in my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It's possible to access through Graph API (or any other way) the list of all users logged in the past to my FB app?
Thanks

Marcello

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get that information, unless you store it in your own database.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how many people using Facebook analytics. You cannot see their usernames, email, etc- you might be able to extend the analytics with some development to include those... but they dont come configured out of the box.

Here is a link to Facebook App Analytics:

https://developers.facebook.com/products/analytics